# Run file and run selection giving different output for the same piece of code in Spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have been practicing Python using the Spyder IDE.
I wrote the following simple code:

```
a=(1,2,3)
print("ID of a is", id(a))
b=(1,2,3)
print("ID of b is", id(b))
```

Then, I used the 'run file(F5)' option in Spyder and my output was:

```
ID of a is 2788962685056
ID of b is 2788962685056
```

Later, I used the 'run selection or current line(F9)' option in Spyder and my output was:

```
  ID of a is 2788958971776
  ID of b is 2788958973440
```

Why is the output different for the same piece of code?

Comment: Probably because when you reran your code you created new, different objects and those have different id's than the first ones.